# What is the difference between Maximum Burst and Maximum Scale Out Limit in Azure Functions App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

Azure Portal provides the ability to set the number of instances an app can scale out to. This is set by the *Maximum Burst* option in the Scale out tab:
[Picture link since I can't post pictures yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLox7.png)

The maximum number of instances can be further be limited by the *Maximum Scale Out Limit*.
So, the question is, why and when should I put different values in those and what is the actual difference between those settings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They all represent the maximum number of instances, but `Maximum Burst` represents the maximum number of instances that the `plan` can scale out, and `Maximum Scale Out Limit` represents the maximum number of instances that the current `Function App` can scale out.

If you set the maximum number of instances of the `plan`, then the maximum number of instances of your `Function App` cannot exceed the maximum number of instances of the `plan`.

[image]